# App.Config in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: c#, web-services, amazon-web-services, soap, lambda

We are currently exploring the use of AWS Lambda functions to integrate between our Service Now ITSM toolset (using SOAP web services) and Amazon components/services.

We are able to build and use a windows forms application in C# to work with the SOAP web services, but this relies on some specific settings in the app.config file, e.g.

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServiceNowSoap">
                <security mode="Transport" >
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="">
                    <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                  </transport>
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="ServiceNowSoap1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

However, there is no provision when working with .NET Core / AWS Lambda for an app.config file. So how does one store and retrieve these types of settings? Without them, I don't know how the integration with Service Now SOAP web services will work? I am familiar with storing values for Lambda functions in parameter store and / or environment variables, but it's unclear to me how to store information like the above.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Did you figure this out JamesMatson?

Comment: Nope. I'm thinking I may have to create a small web app and deploy via Elastic Beanstalk that can act as a 'bridge' between an incoming function and the AWS function(s), so that the bridge can use its own web/app.config to apply the relevant values. Just doesn't feel right..